# Initialization order issues

Tags: c++, initialization, initialization-order

Given the code sample:

```
class B {
    //Some contents.
};

class C {
    private:
        B& b;
};

class A {
    private:
        B b;
        C c;
};
```

Class C has a reference to a b, so it needs to be initialized with it.  Class A contains an instance of B and an instance of C.

My question is: Can I initialize the C instance in A with the B instance in A (assuming I did bother to put the constructors in)?  Secondly, do I need to perform any explicit initialization of the B in A, or is it default initialized since its a class type within a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Member variables are initialised in the order that they are declared in the class declaration (**even if you have them in a different order in the initialisation list of the constructor**), so yes, by the time `c` is being initialised, `b` will be initialised, and you can use `b` to initialise `c`.

As Ricardo Cardenes notes, it will still work even if you declare `c` before `b` in the class definition (which means you will pass `C::C` a reference to an uninitialised `B`) however you cause undefined behaviour if you *use* the object inside `C::C`. It's safer to declare `b` first, because although you may not use `b` inside `C::C` now, you might in the future and forget that the reference refers to an uninitialised `B`, and cause UB.

And no, you do not have to explicitly initialise `b` (unless it is [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)) unless you don't want it to be default-constructed. So this code would be what you want (again, if `B` isn't POD):

```
A::A() : c(b) { }
```

Comment: Note that this will work even if you declare `c` before `b` inside `A`. The result of using `b` inside `c`'s constructor are undefined, though!

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes ah yes you are right, thanks, I added a note about that.

Answer (score 3):

To your first question: you can initialize it by writing constructors like this:

```
C::C(B& bInst): b(bInst){}
A::A():b(), c(b) {}
```

Of course if your constructor of `C` actually uses `b` (instead of just its address), you need to ensure that the initialization order stays the same, so `b` must be declared before `c`, since members are initialized in the order they are declared in (even if the initializaiton list puts them in a different order).

And no you don't need to explicitly initialize B, since it will be default constructed if you don't. Of course if B is a POD this means remaining it uninitialized (while explicitely initializing it using `b()` in the initializer list of `A()` would initialize it to `0`).

Comment: "*And no you don't need to explicitly initialize B, since it will be default constructed if you don't*" It will only be default-constructed if it's not a POD; i.e., it could very well remain uninitialized.

Comment: @ildjarn: Well yeah, but leaving it uninitialized is what I would call default constructing a POD. I will change my answer to reflect that point though.

Comment: If you use a variable that hasn't been initialised though, it's UB, even if it's POD. For instance, `int x; cout << x;` is UB. If `b` is POD, the `b()` is not optional (unless you go on to assign to `b` later before it's used).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since C only contains a reference to a B and not a separate instance, you can put a constructor in C and let A.C.b reference A.B.

B and C inside A are both instantiated/constructed automatically when you create an instance of A.

Comment: What does the reference have to do with it?

Comment: If C contained an actual B instead of a reference to a B, C.b and B would be separate instances of B and could not be the same one.

Comment: Regardless, he wants to initialise one from the other. What that entails precisely is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I initialize the C instance in A with the B instance in A (assuming I did bother to put the constructors in)

Sure.

> Secondly, do I need to perform any explicit initialization of the B in A, or is it default initialized since its a class type within a class?

No, that's fine.